# Increasing a number using if statement

Tags: python

I'm writing a game, which gets faster after a specific number of points. I want to increase speed every time score number is divisible by 50. My problem is to write a function, which increases the number and doesn't decrease it back, when score is over divisible number (e.g. 51). Any hints? Thanks

```py
def difficulty(score):
    g = 2000
    if score % 50 == 0 and score != 0:
        g += 50
    return g
```

Comment: Your g variable should be defined outside of the function so that it doesn't reset to 2000 every time the difficulty function runs. The rest of your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You define `g` in function scope, so `difficulty` can return either `2000` or `2050`, but nothing else.

You can keep a value out of the function:

```py
def difficulty(score):
    if score % 50 == 0 and score != 0:
        return 50
    return 0

g = 2000

while True:  # Or for-loop, depends on your needs
    g += difficulty(score)
    if ...:  # Your condition here
        break

print(g)
```

Comment: thanks, what if i want to decrease it once by 50? when in loop, it's constatnly decreasing while score % 2 = 0, should I add any condition?